# Cannot retrieve push-notifications with VK SDK on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, vk

Ok, I cannot get any push-notifications from VK despite the fact I'm register device in system.

Here's code for registration and I get OK:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("token", App.channel.Uri.ToString());
dic.Add("device_id", Windows.System.UserProfile.AdvertisingManager.AdvertisingId);


VKRequest.Dispatch<VKList<VKUser>>(new VKRequestParameters("account.registerDevice", dic), (res) =>
            {
               //Newtonsoft cannot parse this string
               if (res.ResultString == "{\"response\":1}") //OK
                    result = true;
            });
```

I specified my push-notification as (VK side):

```
Type: WNS
SID: ms-app://s-...
Client Secret: Secret...
```

But when I call `getPushSettings`, I get something like this:

```
{"response":{"disabled":1,"subscribe":"msg, chat, friend","conversations":{"count":3,"items":[{"user_id":122,"sound":1,"disabled_until":0},{"user_id":123,"sound":1,"disabled_until":0},{"user_id":124,"sound":1,"disabled_until":0}]}}}
```

There are no incoming push-notifications.. What can I do?

Comment: You must turn on push notifications on vk/for developers/ my apps /"select your created app"/ settings

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in API version. When I specified "v":"5.37" everything was OK.